# RStudio opens documentation in web browser

Tags: r, rstudio

When I type in the name of the function the help box in RStudio I get the answer opened in the web browser instead of RStudio-help window. The same happens when typing in `?function` for example `?which`. While doing so I also get the following error in the console:

```
> ?which
Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function
Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function
Error in (function ()  : attempt to apply non-function
```

This happened after upgrading R to version 3.1.3 and I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Does anyone know how to fix this - how to make RStudio open the documentation in RStudio window, not in the web browser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RStudio needs to be upgraded to 0.98.1103 or newer version.
The answer was taken from [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202985288-Bug-RStudio-opensdocumentation-in-web-browser)

Answer (score 0):

in R, this works

```
options(help_type = "text")
```

in R Studio, you can open the file `RStudio\R\Options.R` and comment out this part (in my current version line 16-20):

```
# custom browseURL implementation
options(browser = function(url)
{
    .Call("rs_browseURL", url) ;
})
```

Comment: @Soren H. Welling thank you for downvoting an old answer

Comment: @rmuc8 Well seems like it neither worked for potockan 2 days after your answer. Could you edit answer to include for what versions of R and Rstudio, it actually does work?
I learn on meta that old answers which once worked are appreciated and should not down-voted. So my apologies if that's the case. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer/265440#265440