# RStudio errors: "In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field:"

Tags: r, rstudio

The following errors pop up whenever I use the search box in the Help tab - but notably only when the search does not match any functions in any loaded packages. Furthermore, the errors do not show *until* I enter something else in the R Console. So for example I type `xxxxxx` or `cbinddd` in the Help search box, and press Enter. The search might yield some approximate results or not. But no error. Then I enter anything into the Console, say, `print("x")` or whatever, and these show up, always all three:

```
Warning messages:
1: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: title
2: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: keyword
3: In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field: alias
```

It started back when RStudio had a bug where help would open in browser by default ([Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081462/rstudio-opens-documentation-in-web-browser)), but the next update fixed that. The 'Search Results' page would not show initially, but updating R itself fixed that too; but now I have these weird "delayed" errors. I tried reinstalling R and RStudio, changing the help options in .Rprofile.site, tried setting `options("help_type" = "text")` and to `NULL`, nothing seems to help. Note that entering `?xxxxx` and `??xxxxx` do *not* produce these errors.

Seems like an uncommon problem, since googling the error or parts of it yields no useful results. How do I fix it?

*Update: I have R 3.2.2 and RStudio 0.99.486, running on 64bit Windows 8.1, if that helps.*

*Update 2: The .Rprofile file is not the culprit.*

*Updade 3: The error is due to a bug in RStudio, which will hopefully be fixed at some point (cf. comments for details). <s>As such, this question does no longer need an answer.</s>* -> Answered it, since this page still gets hits.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this issue -- is it possible that you have other code in your `.Rprofile` that affects how R's help lookup functions? Do you still see this if you start RStudio with your `.Rprofile` moved out of the way?

Comment: @KevinUshey Nothing in .Rprofile (should have mentioned that), actually there was no .Rprofile in the default working dir (where R looks first) or anywhere else; I tried creating an empty one there, errors remain. I'm suspecting it's something specific to my setup (otherwise surely there would be more hits on google), but I wouldn't want to go reinstalling Windows if there's any chance of fixing that (no restore points before the errors started either).

Comment: Ahh, I can replicate a version of this now. I see the same result when you press enter after inserting an invalid search query; e.g. with `cbindddd<ENTER>`. I'll file an issue for the RStudio team to look at; thanks!

Comment: @KevinUshey Yes, that's exactly what I have. Pressing Enter after a query that yields no suggestions/matches (i.e., an invalid query, if you wish). But it's not "invalid" in the sense that the user might want to look up a function without knowing the exact name, or look into the help files of a function from a package that's not currently loaded (both things I do quite often). Anyhow, good to know it's on its way to be recognized as a bug to be fixed, thanks for that!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it states that an answer is not needed due to an unsubstantiated claim that this is an unfixed software bug in an IDE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this QA still comes up as the no. 1 match for the query `"In .HTMLsearch(query) : Unrecognized search field:"` in Google, I'm just going to leave this here: apparently (as of July 2016, v0.99.902 ), this behaviour, bug or not, still occurs, when you press enter in the Search field to string that does not immediately get an automatic match. Search works, but when you press Enter the next time in the Console, then those warnings appear. According to [RStudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207491627-HTLMSearch-errors-from-the-RStudio-console) they are working on it (or at least were). So the answer is, there's nothing you can do about it until they fix/change it (but it's really a minor inconvenience that does not affect your code, just the IDE usage).

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour can be caused by a search you did previously (even in a previous session) that doesn't get a match. In my case, it occurred because I was looking (in RStudio Help) for a function in a library that was loaded in the previous session, but isn't loaded when I started this session. If it annoys you, just click the home button in the search window of RStudio.